# how to change from list(list(tuple))) to list(set(tuple))

Tags: python, set

Now when I run my code it returns list(list(tuple)) but I want it to be list(set(tuple)). When I am trying to fix my code there is an “TypeError: unhashable type” appears.
** I didn't use import method because my instructor didn't allow me to do so.

```
Hand = set[tuple[str, str]]


def all_card():  # 52 cards
    rank: list[str] = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    suit: list[str] = ['Club', 'Diamond', 'Heart', 'Spade']
    my_card = []
    for i in rank:
        for j in suit:
            my_card.append((i, j))
    return my_card


def all_matches(cards, num):
    if num == 0:
        return [[]]
    L = []
    for i in range(0, len(cards)):
        first = cards[i]
        rem = cards[i + 1:]
        all = all_matches(rem, num - 1)
        for j in all:
            L.append([first] + j)
    print(len(L))
    return L


def all_hands() -> list[Hand]:  # 2,598,960
    my_card = all_card()
    return all_matches(my_card, 5)


print(all_hands())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_matches()` should return `List[Hand]` (= `List[Set[Tuple[str, str]]]`), as `all_hands()` return so.

Lets see what it does return now. In the recursion base condition it is `List[List]`:

```py
if num == 0:
        return [[]]
```

In the recursion code itself, this is also `List[List]`:

```
L = []
...
   L.append([first] + j)
return L
```

We want to edit it to return `List[Set]` (`List[Set[Tuple[str, str]]]`).

In the recursion base condition, we can easily:

```
if num == 0:
        return [set()]
```

In the recursion code we can:

```
        all = all_matches(rem, num - 1)
        for j in all:
            j.add(first)
            L.append(j)
```

As `all` is now `List[Set]` according to the recursion base condition